# How do I change a variable in a script tag in HTML before the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading a webpage that is not mine, so I can't edit the source code. I want to change just one variable in one of it's script tags, that looks like this

```
<script>
    preview=0;
    test=0;
</script>
```

Now in the actual page there is more in between the tags, but that isn't what I'm asking for. I want to change just the `test = 0;` line into `test = 1;` before the rest of the page loads. How can I do this?

Comment: *I am loading a webpage that is not mine* How? Where? More context please

Comment: only if you have access to the server

Comment: I mean like if I were to open up a website, say like go to itch.io, that wouldn't be my website. And max, I'm not trying to change what's on the server, only whats loaded on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a web page before its document has loaded, obviously.

But there is one window event that fires after a document is loaded but before stylesheets, images, and subframes have finished loading.

It's called [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```js
    targetWindow.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        // do your page edits here
    });
```

You will need access to this page's window object. If you're loading the web page into an iframe, see [How to get a reference to an iframe's window object inside iframe's onload handler created from parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018598/how-to-get-a-reference-to-an-iframes-window-object-inside-iframes-onload-handl).