# Targetting main window from iframe in HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, html

I have 2 iframes in an aspx page and in one of the iframe I am loading a new aspx page and in that I have my gallery images. I have inserted pirobox pop up plugin to load each image as pop up. My problem is that the pop up is loading in iframe itself and I want the pop up cover the whole screen so that larger images can be viewed without scrolling in iframe to view it as a whole. Please help me out of this. Do I need to make changes in Javascript or some where in anchor tag itself.

This is my main page:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="C:\Users\guruprasadr\Downloads\pirobox_extended\demo.html" style="margin-left:50px" height="600px" width="700px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This is demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pirobox Extended</title>
<link href="css_pirobox/style_1/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/default.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sansation/stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pirobox_extended.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().piroBox_ext({
    piro_speed : 700,
        bg_alpha : 0.5,
        piro_scroll : true // pirobox always positioned at the center of the page
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="img/26.jpg" rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="Curious kitten.">
            <img src="img/26s.jpg"  />
        </a>
    </li>
<li><a href="Images/300vsSA-Getty.jpg" rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="Lights"><img src="img/27s.jpg"  /></a></li>
<li><a href="img/29.jpg" rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="Sun salutation."><img src="img/29s.jpg"  /></a></li>
<li><a href="img/30.jpg" rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="Bonfire"><img src="img/30s.jpg"  /></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now am I clear guys..

Comment: Yes, we're magicians, but we need some code to work with

Comment: You can't do it with iframe. But, you can use jQuery to load content in `div` and when image is clicked make `div` to go fullscreen by positioning it absolute. IDK, you got what I meant or not.

Comment: Without any code its almost impossible to give an exact anwer. But in my oppinion you need to load the gallery js in the main aspx page and target the child divs of the gallery ifame to open them in the whole window.

Comment: @badZoke I have included the code. do I need to put something more..

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar Can you please show me an example or elaborate it..

Comment: What I am doing here is I am just trying out with an example of html page. I have a project which I am doing it in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and if you include it instead framing it ?

```
<!-- #Include virtual="C:\Users\guruprasadr\Downloads\pirobox_extended\demo.html" -->
```

If you do so, just include what's in between `<body>` tags and Js/CSS `<link>`

have you tried to use `parent.window` to have interaction in between iframe and main document ?
see among others : [Access elements of parent window from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe)

Comment: @GCyrillus.. No No.. I want to load those images in iframe itself as it is the part of design...

Comment: oki , then, i believe iframe has to talk to parent.window so parent.window may do something :)

Comment: @GCyrillus.. let me know if you know about how to make them talk with each other.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe it was near you all that time :)