# How to change web title while in object tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to change title of web page with javascript from `<object>` tag?

this code from **main.html** that include `<object>`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>main title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>home</h1>
    <div>
      <object type="text/html" data="home.html"></object>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in **home.html** i want change **main.html** `<title>` tag with *home title* by click a button

this code from my **home.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="home();">change main title</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this my javascript code

```
function home() {
  window.parent.title = "home title";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly two problems here:

First, `title` is a property of [the `document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/document), it isn't a global. So you need:

```
window.parent.document.title
```

Second, if you open the developer tools in your browser and look at the Console. You may see an error message along the lines of:

> Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "title" on cross-origin object

Communicating across frames isn't possible unless you are loading them from the same origin using HTTP (or HTTPS).

Make sure your documents are loaded from a web server and not directly from your disk.

(Although see the postMessage API).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, this is the best answer i'm looking for. It works perfectly when I run it on the web server 

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.title = ""`.

Something tells me that your time spent on researching has been very limited, but here you go.

Comment: That **won't work**. It changes the title of the document in the frame, not the the one in the parent window.

Comment: @Quentin If I could downvote myself, I would. You are absolutely right! My answer causes a cross origin error. I saw the script.js being included in main.html, so I assumed it was alright. But this causes a `home is undefined` javascript error. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

You can change web-page title via `document.title`

```
function home() {
  document.title = "home title";
}
```

Comment: That **won't work**. It changes the title of the document in the frame, not the the one in the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.parent.document.title` to access the title of the parent document. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe) question.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this. Seems to be working here: [link](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/windowti.htm)

```
function home() {
  window.document.title = "home title";
}
```

Comment: That **won't work**. It changes the title of the document in the frame, not the the one in the parent window.