# Getting the document object of an iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I'm trying to get the document object of an iframe, but none of the examples I've googled seem to help.  My code looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunc(){
                alert("I'm getting this far");
                var doc=document.getElementById("frame").document;
                alert("document is undefined: "+doc);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/ncr" id="frame" width="100%" height="100%" onload="myFync()"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested that I am able to obtain the iframe object, but .document doesn't work, neither does .contentDocument and I think I've tested some other options too, but all of them return undefined, even examples that are supposed to have worked but they don't work for me.  So I already have the iframe object, now all I want is it's document object.  I have tested this on Firefox and Chrome to no avail.

Comment: You just needed to highlight your markup and click the button which looks like `{}` to indent it as code. Ive edited your post to make it clearer.

Comment: Duplicate of [HTML: Getting document from IFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/html-getting-document-from-iframe) and [Invoking javascript in iframe from parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/251420/94197).

Comment: @Jamiec, thanks!  I thought I had to click {} for every new line

Comment: @Andy E, I know it's a duplicate, but the other examples didn't work for me.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try the following

```
var doc=document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument;

// Earlier versions of IE or IE8+ where !DOCTYPE is not specified
var doc=document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.document;
```

Note: AndyE pointed out that `contentWindow` is supported by all major browsers so this may be the best way to go.

- http://help.dottoro.com/ljctglqj.php

Note2: In this sample you won't be able to access the document via any means. The reason is you can't access the document of an iframe with a different origin because it violates the "Same Origin" security policy

- http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: AFAIK, all browsers support the non-standard `contentWindow` property, so it's safest just to go with that.

Comment: @AndyE the documentation I could find didn't give a definitive yes / no on that. Do you have something I could reference?

Comment: only [the dottoro reference](http://help.dottoro.com/ljctglqj.php). It's references are usually (technically) correct.

Comment: @DudeDawg you're running into a same origin violation here. You can't access the `document` of an iframe which comes from a different domain

Comment: @JaredPar, OK, then I understand what's wrong.  I guess I'll try to work around the problem.

Comment: @Andy E, @JaredPar: I think it was older (pre-3.0) versions of Safari that didn't support `contentWindow` but did support `contentDocument`. `contentDocument` made it into a standard long before `contentWindow` (DOM 2 versus HTML5) so I used to favour that but now `contentWindow` is pretty much safe to use on its own.

Comment: @Tim: ah, thanks for clarifying.  If anyone with Safari 2 reads this, well, then I guess they ought to think about upgrading their browser ;-)

Comment: @Commenters, not even a +1 for my pre-Safari 2 safe code :-)?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in 2014 and all the modern browsers?

Answer (score 8):

For even more robustness:

```
function getIframeWindow(iframe_object) {
  var doc;

  if (iframe_object.contentWindow) {
    return iframe_object.contentWindow;
  }

  if (iframe_object.window) {
    return iframe_object.window;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.contentDocument) {
    doc = iframe_object.contentDocument;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.document) {
    doc = iframe_object.document;
  }

  if (doc && doc.defaultView) {
   return doc.defaultView;
  }

  if (doc && doc.parentWindow) {
    return doc.parentWindow;
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

and

```
...
var el = document.getElementById('targetFrame');

var frame_win = getIframeWindow(el);

if (frame_win) {
  frame_win.targetFunction();
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the code I use:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myFrame');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('Hello World!');
ifrm.document.close();
```

> **contentWindow vs. contentDocument**
>
> - IE (Win) and Mozilla (1.7) will return the window object inside the
>     iframe with oIFrame.contentWindow.
> - Safari (1.2.4) doesn't understand that property, but does have
>     oIframe.contentDocument, which points to the document object inside
>     the iframe.
> - To make it even more complicated, Opera 7 uses
>     oIframe.contentDocument, but it points to the window object of the
>     iframe. Because Safari has no way to directly access the window object
>     of an iframe element via standard DOM (or does it?), our fully
>     modern-cross-browser-compatible code will only be able to access the
>     document within the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was due to Same Origin policies. To explain it further, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) states the following:

> If the iframe and the iframe's parent document are Same Origin, returns a Document (that is, the active document in the inline frame's nested browsing context), else returns null.