# contentDocument.document returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to access and modify the iframe content. when I do it like this, Chrome 16 and Firefox 9 return "Cannot read property 'document' of undefined". What I am doing wrong?

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

...

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("frame");
var content = myIFrame.contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML;
alert(content);
```

Comment: use the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570496/getting-the-document-object-of-an-iframe