# Accessing the document object of a frame with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frame

I'm testing on [this page](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html), and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
// Two frames on the page
> document.getElementsByTagName("frame").length
2

// Same domain, so no security restrictions
> document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].src
"http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/menu_1.html"
> window.location.href
"http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html"

// Can't access the document
> document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].document
undefined
```

It seems like this should work, so what's the problem?  It needs to work in IE8, but I'm also testing in Chrome (newest stable).

Comment: Are you actually using frames in 2013, or are those iFrames ?

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].contentDocument`?

Comment: `var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0]; var frame_doc = frame.contentWindow.document || frame.contentDocument;` - then use `frame_doc` as the frame's document

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the document object of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570496/getting-the-document-object-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The all-around way to getting a frame's contents is with something like this:

```
var theFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0];
var theFrameDocument = theFrame.contentDocument || theFrame.contentWindow.document;
var button = theFrameDocument.getElementById("mybutton");
```

However, it is possible to get a `<frame>`'s document by using its name, like:

```
window.frames["frame_name"].document
```

if the HTML were:

```
<frame name="frame_name">...</frame>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
parent.frame.location.href = ...
```

Where frame is the name/id of the frame you d like to change.

Greets
Marc