# access the content of a about:blank iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, firebug

From the Firebug JavaScript console is it possible to access the content of an `<iframe>` object whose `src` property is set to `about:blank`?
I've tried with:

```
var b=document.getElementById("iframe_ID");
console.log(b.innerHTML);
```

but it returns

```
(an empty string)
```

Comment: I thought `about:blank` is supposed to be void of content. What would you expect instead of an empty string?

Comment: I want to do some test for a web page that is not written by me.

Comment: Looks like the question is actually unrelated to about:blank but rather asking about how to access an iframe's document via JavaScript, so probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944699/accessing-the-document-object-of-a-frame-with-javascript.

Answer (score 1):

With `document.getElementById("iframe_ID").innerHTML` you just get the HTML content within the iframe element of the current document, **not** the iframe's document. I.e. if you have your iframe defined like this:

```
<iframe src="someDocument.html" id="iframe_ID"></iframe>
```

you get the contents between the opening `<iframe>` tag and the closing `</iframe>` tag, i.e. an empty string in this case.

To access the iframe's content you need to call this:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_ID").contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML
```

See also [Accessing the document object of a frame with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944699/accessing-the-document-object-of-a-frame-with-javascript).

Though note that there are some security restrictions when trying to access the iframe's content as described in an [answer to a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729590/432681).