# Can't get powershell to click a button on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell, internet-explorer

I am trying to automate the downloading of a csv file from a website. 
The submit button in the login form is the only succesful button clicked but the other buttons inside the page is not responding to the commands.
here is my code
[image]
this is the html of the button I am trying to click by powershell script
[image]

I already tried this codes

```
$btn = $IE.Document.getElementsByClassName('btn_schedule_search')  | Select-Object -First 1
$btn.Click()

$IE.Document.getElementsByClassName('btn_schedule_search').Click()

$IE.Document.querySelector('[class="btn_schedule_search"]').Click() 

$btn =$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object{$_.type -eq 'button' -and $_.value -eq '一 覧'}
$btn.Click()
```

I even used -Match and -Like. Nothing seemed to be working. Please help.

here is the sample, most of the time this error displays
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByTagName` shoud definitely work. The reason that the result is `$null` may be the `where` closure. Try to get all elements without filtering by `value` property:

```
$buttons = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.Type -match "button"}
```

And do you have encoding set in your page? To handle `value` in Chinese try this in your page header:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
```

Also, a useful post for those, who using frames: [Accessing the document object of a frame with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14944876/4535033)

Comment: The page has charset="utf-8". I tried your suggestion but its still not working. Is there any necessary extension I should install or something? I am a beginner in powershell. I only installed Powershell extension.

Comment: You mean that $buttons is still $null? For me it's working with stock browser and PS session. But without correct charset the $value I get is incorrect.

Comment: yeah I already tried this codes

btn = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")  | Where-Object {$_.class -match 'btn_schedule_search' -and $_.type -match 'button'}

$btn.Click()

btn = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")  | Where-Object {$_.class -match 'btn_schedule_search' -and $_.type -match 'button' -and $_.value -match '一 覧'}

$btn.Click()

Comment: I used getElementsByTagName and used class, type or even value in where-object. the only thing left is the onclick property

Comment: I read in a forum, "button is inside an iframe. Iframes dont extrapolate their elements into the parent document object. You would need first get the frame's document and then search on the frame's document for the element to click it.". Can this be a possible cause? I don't have any knowledge about the iframe.

Comment: Yes. If your page contains an IFrame, then elements inside it will not be available for $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName. But it's not clear from your example if you're using IFrame's in your page.

Comment: <frame name="menu" src="../common/cmn003.do?menuPage=1" noresize="true" scrolling="no"></frame> and <frameset rows="90,*" cols="1" frameborder="no">
  <frame name="menu" src="../common/cmn003.do?menuPage=1" noresize="true" scrolling="no"></frame>
  <frame name="body" src="../schedule/sch010.do" scrolling="yes"></frame>
</frameset> is used. is this it?

Comment: Yes, the frame is the reason it didn't work. Added a link in my answer, which might be helpful.