# JS - getElementById inside a frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

I'm trying to insert into my webpage a form which is located in an external webpage.

I don't have the direct url to this form, so I'm trying to navigate the frame in this way:

```
function showForm() {
        var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        newIframe.width = '800'; newIframe.height = '400';
        newIframe.src = "websiteURL"
        document.body.appendChild(newIframe);
        window.frames["iframe"].document.getElementById('HM_Item1_4_1_1').click();
    }
```

But from the console I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iframe' of undefined
```

The homepage of the external website is loaded, but the redirection isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get `window.frames["iframe"]` … but the iframe you created doesn't have a `name` or `id` at all, let alone that matches `"iframe"`.

It's pointless searching the frames collection for the iframe anyway.

You **already have a reference to it** in the `newIframe` variable!

Just replace `window.frames["iframe"]` with `newIframe`.

---

Once you fix that, your next problem is that [`document` is the wrong property to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944699/accessing-the-document-object-of-a-frame-with-javascript).

---

Once you fix that, your next problem is that you said the iframe pointed to a different site. So you have to deal with [cross-origin issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393532/cross-domain-iframe-issue).

Comment: @Pickeroll — That's a long-winded and bloated approach. Just use `newIframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you may come across different security and *cross-origin* errors while doing this.

Remember to wait for the iframe contents to load before acting on it using the **onload** event:

```
function showFrame() {
        const newFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
        newFrame.width = '800';
        newFrame.height = '800';
        newFrame.src = 'https://www.gorkahernandez.com';
        newFrame.onload = function() {
            const content = newFrame.contentDocument ? newFrame.contentDocument : newFrame.contentWindow.document;
            content.getElementById('HM_Item1_4_1_1').click();

        }
        document.body.appendChild(newFrame);
    }
```