# make HTML page's element accessible in another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an HTML page say `main.html` which has an `iframe` (say `id="myFrame"`)showing `child.html` page. **Both** of these pages have a button called "Hide frame". The onclick of these buttons calls `hideFrame()` JS function which is declared in `main.js` file. The `hideFrame()` function just change the display of `myFrame` to "none".

```
function hideFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display = "none";
}
```

The `myFrame` is in `main.html` file so the button in `main.html` when calls the `hideFrame()` function, it works. The frame gets hidden. But the same is not working if I call the function from `child.html` page.

How can I access this element (`myFrame`) form `child.html` page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the document object of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570496/getting-the-document-object-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the main.html's window object to assign the function to. So instead of

```
function hideFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display = "none";
}
```

you would do something like

```
window.hideFrame = function(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display = "none";
}
```

Now the function is globally scoped on main.html's window.

The child frame has it's own window object. You need access to the parent window object to call the function from child.html.

From main.html, you can call hideFrame normally on click `onclick = hideFrame()`, but in child.html, you should put `onclick = window.parent.hideFrame()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an iFrame, I would use jquery to load in segments of html files from other files.

If that is not possible, you could inject Javascript code into the child frame that references objects in the parent. Ex:

child:

```
<script>
    var x;
</script>
```

parent:

```
<script>
    $("#myFrame").x = function(){
        functionality / reference definitions
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a while to understand what you are saying. From what I understand, you want to get access to an element on the top window from inside an iframe. Here is what to get access to the parent window:

`var _parent =     window.parent,
     _parent_dom = _parent.document;`

Then to get access to an element from the parent page (in this case `#myFrame`):

`var my_frame = _parent_dom.getElementById("myFrame");`