# Cant we get location of iframe which has navigated to external site?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe , user navigated to certain location of external site in that iframe . Now i have a button that on click tells the location of that site (using .location.href) but it alerts undefined ? My site was ideone.com . How can i get its current URL ? Any correction or alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

Due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot access any information from an `iframe` which has its location set to a different domain then the parent.

If you look at your browser's console (F12) you will probably see an error similar to this (this one is from Chrome)

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://othersite.com/ from frame with URL
>   http://yoursite.com. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to access the `window` of the iframe, which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999154/1883647) you should be able to do via:

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.location.href
```

Get a reference to your iframe however you wish, of course, as the key is `.contentWindow`. However, as that link indicates, if it is another domain, then the Same Origin Policy prevents you from getting the `window` reference.