# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById('step1').innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('code1').value = document.getElementById('google_ads_frame1').src;
    document.technical1.submit();
}
```

> o erro se encontra na linha
>                   document.getElementById'step1').innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')**[0].contentDocument.document.body.innerHTML;**

[image]

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: Please show us your HTML-Code aswell

Comment: You can get your problem solved for free by providing enough code here to duplicate the error. Please [edit] your question to include a working demo of your code (the HTML & JS as requested). This is not a site where you pay for help and your offer of money is inappropriate here.

Comment: [Even more free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) ... no need to even bother to edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use just `contentDocument.body` instead of `contentDocument.document.body`:

```
document.getElementById('step1').innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

---

Or `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument`:

```
document.getElementById('step1').innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

`iframe.contentDocument` is the same as `iframe.contentWindow.document`

[HTML: Getting document from IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/html-getting-document-from-iframe)

Comment: Umh... Reading the error message, it tells, that `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` returns an empty collection ...

Comment: that is new.. I guess it can't find any iframe-tag. We need the HTML-Code