# DOM click on a href

Tags: javascript, dom, applescript

Sorry for my lack of understanding of HTML/JavaScript, but I'm trying to simply click a button on a webpage to submit a form. The following is the html profile of the "submit" button.

```
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSave">Submit</i></a>
```

I'm attempting to use the following JavaScript to click on it.

```
document.getElementById('btnSave').click()
```

I understand that sometimes DOM `click()` doesn't always work, but I'm unable to come up with another solution or even understand why it won't.

Just for some background information, I don't own the website so I can't change the button code or the JavaScript. I'm attempting to run my JavaScript though AppleScript in Safari.

If I need to post the original page's JavaScript, I'll gladly do it.

Comment: can you get the button object? try to alert(document.getElementById('btnSace')), or it is a typo, should be btnSave instead?

Comment: @VincentZhang 'twas a typo

Comment: Does `document.getElementById('btnSave')` actually fetch the button?

Comment: @H77 How can I check? Sorry, this is the extent of my JavaScript experience :P

Comment: You can try what @VincentZhang suggested. i.e. the alert (with the proper spelling).

Comment: replace your code with my alert code, if you can get the button, it will alert object, otherwise undefined or some other error will happen.

Comment: Result: `javascript:`

Comment: What's the URL of the page that has the button? Also, how are you implementing it in AppleScript?

Comment: I'm implementing it in AppleScript using the "do JavaScript" command. I've solved my issue, but I will probably post my own answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using `document.getElementById('btnSave').children[0].click();`

I'm not exactly why this worked other than because `getElementById('btnSave')` probably returned multiple results, and since I no longer have access to the page I can't investigate further.

Hope this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you do not have access to button code I am assuming it is an iframe and thus Assuming you have the appropriate access rights. You can use javascript to perform the button click event as I have tried in [this snippet](https://codepen.io/damitj07/pen/BYVWbg).

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
```

Please note the cross-origin restrictions imposed by browsers, which will not allow you to invoke scripts across different domains.

> However, you will not be able to do this if the page in the frame is loaded from a different domain (such as google.com). This is because of the browser's Same Origin Policy.

[Reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999154/5617140)

Comment: So, your example worked, but not as you intended. By calling on "children", I was actually able to get the correct functionality.

Comment: It was just for reference :) as I was working on different site and children wad to access that particular element