# Remove event from iframe's document-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

So there's this iFrame that I can access easily using the .contents() method.

I'd like to remove the 'keypress' event that seems to be assigned to the iFrame's document-element and that prevents me from typing with the keyboard.

I can remove it manually using: Inspect > Eventlisteners > keypress > document > remove

After that, I can type.

So I was wondering if there was a way to remove the event by code, using jQuery.

By the way, I already know how to remove events from elements like 'body' 'div' 'p' and so on. But I can't get the syntax for the '#document' itself.

here is a preview of the iFrame's code. Thanks a lot.

```
<iframe src=(unknown) frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="textUpItemDisplay" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" id="myIframe">
#document
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<title data-cke-title="textUpItemDisplay">textUpItemDisplay</title>
</head>

<body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl" spellcheck="false">

<p style="font-family: &quot;DIN Next LT Arabic Light&quot;; color: rgb(54, 54, 125);">
SOMETEXT
</p>

</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: `#document` isn't an id.  The iframe document is the document under the iframes content window.  You can search on Stack Overflow for how to access an iframes document with javascript and find existing questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IFrame's document, from JavaScript in main document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/get-iframes-document-from-javascript-in-main-document)