# Run javascript on a specific execution context (iframe)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am trying to write javascript code (and put it in a bookmarklet later) that will autofill some textbox on a webpage.

```
document.getElementById("textboxID").value = "Some Text"
```

The problem i have seems to be execution context. This code works **only** if i inspect element first, or if manually change execution context form *top* to the one selected (ext-gen65).
[image: Execution context list (Chrome)].

Whats is the (or is there) a proper way to do this?

EDIT:
When i use `document.getElementById('ext-gen65').contentWindow.document` i get *Cannot read propery 'document' of undefined* error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IFrame's document, from JavaScript in main document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/get-iframes-document-from-javascript-in-main-document)

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Might be a timing issue, if you execute this before the iframe has loaded? If that’s not it, then check what `document.getElementById('ext-gen65').contentWindow` returns first - do you get a window instance, or is that null/undefined already?

Comment: It does return a window instance. 
WillhemVanderVeen answer solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the ID is inside the document of the  Iframe, each Iframe has its own window.document property where your element is located.
You can get the document in the following manner:

```
let Iframe =  document.getElementById('yourIframe').contentWindow.document

let value = Iframe.getElementById("textboxID").value = "Some Text"
```