# How to get body of cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I need to catch iframe body content from cross domain
[image]

However iframe's content document == null,

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999101/get-iframes-document-from-javascript-in-main-document

Comment: you can't access cross origin iframes